# Ajax request not working in IE with jQuery

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, jquery

We are facing a peculiar problem of ajax request not being send using jquery.
Interestingly, it works on IE8 but not on below versions.
I have tried (al)most all of the things mentioned in other related posts but no success.

May be I am missing something big here. But IE seems to be creating lots of trouble both from functionality and css dev perspective. :(

Our web app is based on rails.

Any helps/pointers would be great.

Thanks.

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
   cache: true,
   'beforeSend': function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript")}
});

$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, request, settings) {
  if (typeof(AUTH_TOKEN) == "undefined") return;  
  if ( settings.type != 'GET' &&  settings.type != 'get') {
      settings.data = settings.data || "";
      settings.data = (settings.data ? settings.data + "&" : "")
         + "authenticity_token=" + encodeURIComponent( AUTH_TOKEN );
  }
});
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".signup").live('click', function() {
    var a_key = $('#f_auths').find('input[name="a_key"]').val();
    var a_uid =  $('#f_auths').find('input[name="a_uid"]').val();
    var a_provider =$('#foreign_auths').find('input[name="a_provider"]').val();
    $(this).closest('form').find('input[name="user[provider]"]').val(a_provider);
    $(this).closest('form').find('input[name="user[key]"]').val(a_key);
    $(this).closest('form').find('input[name="user[uid]"]').val(a_uid);

    $.ajax({
      url: "/users",
      type: 'POST',
      data: $(this).closest('form').serialize() ,
      beforeSend: function(){
        $('#loading').css('display','block'); 
      },
      success: function(){

        $('loading').css('display','none');
      },
    });
    return false;
```

});

Comment: Good luck, IE is a plague for web developers introducing too much specific code.

Comment: The question is too general. Without providing some code, expected and actual behavior, it can't be answered. Mentioning the jQuery version used may be of help as well.

Comment: We need to see the code which has the issue, and we need to know the error that IE < 8 is flagging.

Comment: just for the record: http://hey-it.com/

Comment: You haven't stated the actual problem!

Comment: @apneadiving one of the objectives of jQuery is to be cross-browser library. Your answer is not of any help neither for clarifying the question, nor for answering it.

Comment: @Darhazer: I didn't write any answer, that's the point. My comment is just some kind of support. Whether or not it's useful is answering the question: should we only write about code

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble before with this too. In my case, changing the "type" setting in the Ajax call fixed it. I remember another case where my server was actually sending a slightly wrong mimetype back to the client, so double check the content type sent back from your server script. Hope maybe some of that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Install [Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18359) that will help a lot to find out JavaScript problems if you turn back the script debugging checkboxes in options.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the trailing comma (,), after the last parameter (success). It breaks IE 7.

Answer (score 0):

I once had a problem with jQuery and ajax request where IE7 had a problem parsing the '#' character in the url. After getting rid of the # everything worked as expected.